# Im trying to display the file but i get this error Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have form where the user fill it and send it along with a file to the admin, and the admmin should receive the data in data grid......the inputs like name and phone and email i retrive it and display it correctly but  the file i retrieve it and the filePreview also  and i tried to display it but i got this error : this error Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

```
 const Form = () => {
      const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        assurance: "",
        message: "",
        file: null,
        filePreview: null 
      });
      const handleInput = (e) => {
        if (e.target.name === "file") {
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          const filePreview = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
          setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: file, filePreview });
        } else {
          setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }
      };
    
      const uploadFile = async (file) => {
        try {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
          const filename = file.name;
          const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/backend/upload", formData);
          console.log("File uploaded successfully", response.data);
          return filename; 
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
          throw new Error("Error uploading file");
        }
      };
```

and this the component where i display it
name phone email and ect.....

```
  const [selectedFormData, setSelectedFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        assurance: '',
        file:'',
        filePreview:''  
        
      });
```

handleCellClick when i click in message cell i got this data and the file

```
**const handleCellClick = (params) => {
    if (params.field === 'message') {
      const { name, phone, email, assurance, file } = params.row;
      const filePreview = URL.createObjectURL(file) ; 
      setSelectedMessage(params.value);
      setSelectedFormData({ name, phone, email, assurance, file, filePreview }); 
      setOpenModal(true);
    }
  };
<Modal open={openModal} onClose={handleCloseModal} className="modal-container">
        <Slide direction="up" in={openModal} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
          <div className="modal-content" style={{ background: "white" }}>
            <Typography variant="h5">Selected Form</Typography>
            <p>Name: {selectedFormData.name}</p>
            <p>Phone: {selectedFormData.phone}</p>
            <p>Email: {selectedFormData.email}</p>
            <p>Assurance: {selectedFormData.assurance}</p>
            <p>Message: {selectedMessage}</p>
            <p>File: {selectedFormData.file}</p>
                
    
                <div className="action-buttons">
                  <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleCloseModal}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Slide>
          </Modal>**
```